# Why can't I gather some archaeology nodes?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

My Sith Sorcerer is an archaeologist and fairly frequently, I'll see a crystal formation on my minimap, head over to it, but I am unable to use it.  My cursor does not change to the "gather" icon, and clicking on it does nothing, with or without my companion.

They appear to be the exact same type as ones I can harvest (that give me Rubat crystals), could there be some actual difference that's hidden to me and I lack the requisite level to gather them?  Is this a glitch?

Answer (score 7):

There seemed to be some glitched resource nodes.

At a guess, they occur when someone "mines" a node but doesn't actually take the resource... no one else can mine the node, and the node doesn't disappear because it was never actually taken.

Comment: I'm guessing they will fix this, likely how WoW does it... once you close a mining node in WoW, it can be mined by someone else.

Comment: When I gather something it's picked up automatically, without the prompt coming up like for looting.  Is there actually a way to do it and leave the resource behind?

Comment: It's only possible when you don't have a companion with you. Hit ESC exactly when the progressbar for mining is full.

Comment: @user13278 Actually, it also happens if you hold shift while clicking a resource node (which causes you to loot it yourself).

Comment: Also happens if your companion is busy at the time (eg channelling a heal), then it reverts to your character doing the scan/loot.

Comment: I've had it happen when it was me or my companion gathering the node. You just have to cancel the gathering prior to actually collecting the item. I manage to do it all time by trying to mount my speeder to quickly after gathering a node.

Answer (score 2):

The [Patch 1.2.7 notes](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/1.2.7/6122012) say this has been fixed:

> - Corrected an issue that could prevent players from gathering from some resource nodes that appeared to be lootable.

**Currently, you will encounter this very rarely.**  If someone completes the gathering channel on a node but does not actually pick up the material, the node will be inaccessible to others for a short time until it respawns.  The previous issue occurred due to the respawn timer starting when the material was picked up, which obviously was a bad idea if you could leave without picking it up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that is fixed in the current Public Test build. It should be fixed in the next patch.

> Corrected an issue that could cause some gathering nodes to appear as unharvestable.

[Source.](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=71457)